# Append multiple variable from same dataset into single variable

Tags: sas

Given the following dataset:.

```
obs var1 var2 var3
1   123  456  .
2   123  .    789
3   .    456  789
```

How does one go about to append all the variables into a single variable whilst ignoring the empty observations (denoted by ".")?

Desired output:.

```
obs var4
1   123
2   123
3   456
4   456
5   789
6   789
```

Data step:.

```
data have;
input
var1   var2   var3; cards;
123    456    .   
123    .      789 
.      456    789 
;run;
```

Comment: is the order of the output dataset important?

Comment: @keith The order of output is not important. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you read the numbers in as char, but if I change to num, it could be done like this:

```
data have;
  input var1 var2 var3;
  cards;
123    456    .   
123    .      789 
.      456    789 
;run;
data want (keep=var4);
  set have;
  var4=var1;if var4 ne . then output;
  var4=var2;if var4 ne . then output;
  var4=var3;if var4 ne . then output;
run;
```

Comment: I was looking more towards a dynamic solution so say in an example with 99 variables one wouldn't need to repeat the same code 99 times

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's assume you have a file vith the values in it, and you do not know how many variables are in each row. First I need to create a sample textfile:

```
filename x temp;
data _nulL_;
  file x;
  put "123    456    .   ";
  put "123    .      789 ";
  put ".      456    789 ";
run;
```

Then I need to read the first line and count the number of variables:

```
data _null_;
  infile x;
  input;
  call symputx("number_of_variables",put(countw(_infile_," ","c"),best.));
  stop;
run;
%put &number_of_variables;
```

Now I can dynamically read the variables:

```
%macro doit();
data have;
  infile x;
  input
  %do i=1 %to &number_of_variables;
    var&i
  %end;
  ;
run;
data want (keep=var%eval(&number_of_variables + 1));
  set have;
  %do i=1 %to &number_of_variables;
    var%eval(&number_of_variables + 1)=var&i;
    if var%eval(&number_of_variables + 1) ne . then output;
  %end;
run;
%mend;
%doit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `proc transpose` to do this but there is a trick to doing so.  You will need to append a unique identifier to each row, prior to doing the transpose.

I've taken @Stig's sample data and added the observation number to use as a unique identifier:

```
data have;
  input var1 var2 var3;
  x = _n_;  * ADDING A UNIQUE IDENTIFIER TO EVERY ROW;
  cards;
123    456    .   
123    .      789 
.      456    789 
;run;
```

Then it's simply a case of running proc transpose:

```
proc transpose data=have out=xx;
  by x;
run;
```

And finally,  remove any results where col1 is missing, and add in the observation number:

```
data want;
  obs = _n_;
  set xx (keep=col1);
  where col1 ne .;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the order is not important then you can do this in one step, using arrays.  As the data step moves through each row, the array enables the variable values to be stored in memory, so you can loop through them.  I've set it up so that each time a non-missing value is found, then output it to the new variable.

In creating the array, I've set it to var1--var3, the double dash means all variables between var1 and var3 inclusive.  If your real variables are numbered the same way then you can use var1-var3, which means all sequential numbers between the two variables.

```
data have;
input var1 var2 var3; 
datalines;
123 456 .
123 . 789
. 456 789
;
run;

data want;
set have;
array allnums var1--var3;
do i = 1 to dim(allnums);
    if not missing(allnums{i}) then do;
    var4 = allnums{i};
    output;
    end;
end;
drop var1--var3 i;
run;
```